# LibVLC fails to show subtitles for streamed video

Tags: java, android, video, libvlc

I tried to create a video player on android device, which could stream videos from local server. I found an [this](https://bitbucket.org/edwardcw/libvlc-android-sample) example. I followed to the guideline and at the end I was able to play local video on my device. Then I started to modify this project. I set VideoActivity as launcher activity and commented out all data received from previous activity. I modified initialization of media from

```
Media m = new Media(libvlc, media);
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
```

to

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://samples.mplayerhq.hu/MPEG-4/embedded_subs/1Video_2Audio_2SUBs_timed_text_streams_.mp4");
Media m = new Media(libvlc, uri);
mMediaPlayer.setMedia(m);
```

Added 2 new methods (as you see, those methods are dummy methods simply to see the result)

```
private void setSubtitles(){
    MediaPlayer.TrackDescription[] tds = mMediaPlayer.getSpuTracks();
    mMediaPlayer.setSpuTrack(tds[tds.length - 1].id);
}

private void seekTo(long time) {
    mMediaPlayer.setTime(time);
}
```

And called them on play event

```
@Override
    public void onEvent(MediaPlayer.Event event) {
        VideoActivity player = mOwner.get();

        switch(event.type) {
            case MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached:
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayerEndReached");
                player.releasePlayer();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Playing:
 --->           player.seekTo(1000);
 --->           player.setSubtitles();
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Paused:
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Stopped:
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
```

But when ever I tried to play the video, I got `12401-12591/? A/libc﹕ @@@ ABORTING: INVALID HEAP ADDRESS IN dlfree`. I get this error some seconds after subtitles ar shown (Also subtitles are too small). This error is shown only when I try to show subtitles. Without subtitles video is playing without any error.

I tried to play this video on VLC application and it was able to show subtitles. I tried to create new project - got the same error. I analysed VLC android source code and it looks that they are using almost the same logic for loading subtitles (Only setting different surfaceViews for video and subtitles, but it gave me the same error). So what am I missing? What does cause player to brake and how to fix it? Maybe there is already working example of code for showing subtitles.

Comment: also interested in this...

Comment: No, I didn't find an answer. As a had a limited time to do that task, I simply made a custom subtitle file parser and showed the parsed data in custom modified text view element. It worked perfectly and also gave me an additional possibilities to adjust the look of subtitles